# Calculadora En Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo un código con clases para una calculadora pero lo tengo solo para operar 2 números.
Alguien me podría hacer el favor de dar una guía o instrucción como hago para poder operar varios números y al oprimir igual me muestre el resultado completo.
Ya que en el código que tengo no puedo operar mas de 2 números. 
Lo estoy haciendo con una clase donde tengo los métodos de las operaciones.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Ademas por favor, no repliques tu pregunta una y otra vez. Asi no funciona el sitio. lee por favor el [tour]